# Celery and Twitter streaming api with Django

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, twitter-streaming-api

I'm having a really hard time conceptualising how I can connect to the the twitter streaming api and process tweets via an admin interface provided by Django.

The main problem is starting a daemon from Django and having the ability to stop/start it, plus making sure there is provision for monitoring.  I don't really want to use upstart for this purpose because I want to try and keep the project as self contained as possible.

I'm currently attempting the following and am unsure if it's perhaps the wrong way to go about things

- Start a celery task from Django which establishes a persistent connection to the streaming API
- The above task creates subtasks which will process tweets and store them
- Because celeryd runs as a daemon it will automatically run the first task again if the connection breaks and the task fails - does this mean I don't need any additional monitoring?

Does the above make sense or have I misunderstood how celery works?